# Access Denied for anonymous users - Sharepoint 2010 - ComException 0x810200ce

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

When anonymous users try to access sites in our main SharePoint site collection they are presented with the following error message:

[image: Access Denied - ComException 0x810200ce]

Some notes:

a) We have Output Cache enabled on the site collection.

b) The problem seems to come and go - previously stopping and starting iis seemed to fix it.

c) We recently ran this:
Set-SPSite -Identity oursitecollection -UserAccountDirectoryPath “ourdomainsldap”

We did this to prevent other users in our AD Forest being available to select on our people picker.

d) Anonymous access is enabled on the Web Application, Site Collection and Sites in question.

e) This is a similar question -

[Similar Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39243/you-do-not-have-permission-to-perform-this-action-or-access-this-resource-nativ)

However I want the users in question to be anonymous on the site - but still have access to the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think we found the answer.

The Style Resource Readers group had NT Authority\Authenticated Users in it.

I took that out and replaced it with the domain\domain users and everything seemed to start working.